# Why /user/local/go isn't recognized as a Go SDK in GoLand

Tags: go, wsl-2, goland

I'm trying to setup GoLand to use WSL 2 as in this guide: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/go/how-to-use-wsl-development-environment-in-product.html

I've installed Go in the Ubuntu distro following the linux instructions on the GoLang website, and `go version` prints outs the version I downloaded, so it appears that Go is working inside WSL.

[image: printing go version]

So now I tried to create a new project in GoLand, and I'm getting errors, which appear to come from the fact that the SDK isn't loaded in GoLand. The guide doesn't offer much guidance on this, so I just tried to add a local SDK.

When I select `/usr/local/go` I get an error that it's not a valid SDK.
[image: invalid sdk dir error]

So I created the `~/go` directory, and then updated my `.zshrc` file to export the `GOPATH` and `GOROOT` environment variables, even though they already showed up when I ran `go env`, doing this got them to show up on a simple `env` call.

But I'm still getting the invalid SDK error like above.

Is there a configuration step I'm missing that isn't spelled out in the guide? I came across [this old post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19108421/the-selected-directory-is-not-a-valid-home-for-go-sdk) about creating symlinks to fake the expected directory structure. I haven't done this because it's a really old post, has comments that say this has been fixed, and seems like a really odd solution.

Comment: "to export the GOPATH and GOROOT environment variables" normal users **NEVER** need to set GOROOT and GOPATH is deprecated. Please read and follow https://golang.org/doc/#getting-started (and do not post images).

Answer (score 2):

Support for Go SDK in WSL2 will be available in the next 2021.3 release, please see [GO-10618](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/GO-10618).

**October 2021 update.**

2021.3 reaches [Early Access Program](https://www.jetbrains.com/go/nextversion/) at the moment. GoLand suggests selecting Go SDK on WSL2 mount if the location of the project is on WSL2 as well.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this on my Debian machine and I wasn't using WSL2. I found that the actual cause of the issue is that Goland is unable to read the directory `/usr/local/go/bin` due to inadequate permission.

A possible solution is to run the goland.sh script as root. The script can be found in the bin/goland.sh directory of the Goland IDE folder. Here is a simple command to do run Goland as the root
`export HISTIGNORE='*sudo -S*' && echo "sudo-password-here" | sudo -S /absolute-path-to-goland.sh`

`export HISTIGNORE='*sudo -S*'` tells bash history to ignore caching any command matching sudo -S* to bash history. This way, your sudo-password isn't saved into the bash-history file.

`echo "sudo-password-here" |` pipes your sudo password as input to the next command.

sudo -S tells bash to read input for password prompt from stdin, which has been provided through the `echo` command.

Alternatively, you can just install the latest version of Goland. Hopefully, it doesn't come with this bug